# Problems selecting a photo or image from the cell phone

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a problem with views, when I open the camera and take the photo it sends me directly to the home screen, the same happens with an image of the gallery, this only happens with ios, since Android works without any problem. I would like to know what is happening because I have not found the error.

```
public async Task TakePicture()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "No se encontro una cámara disponible.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = false,
                CompressionQuality = 30,
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small
            });

            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] array;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                while (count < 10)
                {
                    if (array.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }

            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
            var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            FotoPerfil = image;
            User.Foto = array;

        }
```

This part is to take the photo directly from the cell phone, I have no problem opening the camera, the error comes when I choose that photo sends me to another screen, I do not know if it is closing and reopening the application but I do not know what happens.

```
public async Task PickPicture()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error",
                    "No se otorgaron permisos para accesar a las fotos.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
            {
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                CompressionQuality = 30,

            });


            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            byte[] array;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                while (count < 10)
                {
                    if (array.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }

            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", array.ToString(), "OK");
            User.Foto = array;
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
            var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            FotoPerfil = image;
        }
```

The latter is to select any image from the gallery, and exactly the same happens.

Comment: have you tried running it in the debugger on your device to capture the exception causing the crash?

Comment: I already did everything, I already made the debug and everything well in the code, there is another view where I occupy the same structure and it shows without problem the image or photo, but in others it is where the error of sending me to another view occurs I do not know if it Close for any problems before or navigation problems.

Comment: In addition this error only occurs on ios devices, on Android it works perfectly.

Comment: Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #14
Navigation stack: TabPage
2019-07-26 12:31:37.562166-0500 HomieProveedorApp.iOS[5878:419099] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"UserInfo{NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}Thread started:  #16